# Android Firebase - How Can I Access the data from the inner child using a query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database structure.

[image]

How will I query to access all the details using a userID (that was indicated on the photo too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a specific object, you must know something that unique identifies that object. To get the data under that random id using a query, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("WantToBuy").child(uid).orderByChild("packhename").equalsTo("Makati");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String packhename = ds.child("packhename").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, packhename);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Makati
```

Comment: Good luck with that and keep me poested.

Comment: Hi jt1017! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Yes sir it worked now i have another question, how can i get the user id of a specific node shown above? So for example i want to get the user id of the boxed node. How will i get that. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) but let's stick to one question at a time. This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.